# Optimizing the mysql query

Tags: mysql

Following query is taking really long to execute:

```
SELECT HISTORY.VERSION_ID
     , HISTORY.ACTION
     , HISTORY.STATUS
     , HISTORY.APP_INSTANCE
     , HISTORY.ACTION_TIMESTAMP

FROM
  HISTORY
WHERE
  HISTORY.HISTORY_ID IN (SELECT max(H.HISTORY_ID) AS expr1 FROM HISTORY H GROUP BY H.VERSION_ID)

GROUP BY
  HISTORY.VERSION_ID
, HISTORY.ACTION
, HISTORY.STATUS
, HISTORY.APP_INSTANCE

, HISTORY.ACTION_TIMESTAMP
```

Other important things related to tables are :

Table:

```
Field               Type        Null    Key Default     Extra

HISTORY_ID          bigint(20)  NO  PRI (null)      auto_increment
VERSION_ID          bigint(20)  YES MUL (null)  
ACTION              varchar(50) YES     (null)  
STATUS              varchar(100)    YES     (null)  
ACTION_TIMESTAMP        timestamp   NO      CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   
APP_INSTANCE            varchar(50) YES     (null)  
TIME_TO_COMPLETE_PROCESS    bigint(35)  YES     (null)
```

Indexes :

```
HISTORY 0   PRIMARY         1   HISTORY_ID  A   89  (null)  (null)      BTREE   

HISTORY 1   FK_HISTORY      1   VERSION_ID  A   44  (null)  (null)  YES BTREE
```

Explain Query :

```
1   PRIMARY         HISTORY     ALL (null)  (null)      (null)  (null)  472468  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort

2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  H       index   (null)  FK_HISTORY  9   (null)  6   Using index
```

Please help me in optimizing the query.

Thanks,
Sachin

Comment: Can you post the results of the query... I believe it would be returning only one record. though not clear,  but I doubt so. Please post the result to clear the doubt, so that I can help you further

Comment: No, the query is not returning only one record. It is returning around 50k records. Let me know if you want to view few results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  h.VERSION_ID,
        h.ACTION,
        h.STATUS,
        h.APP_INSTANCE,
        h.ACTION_TIMESTAMP
FROM    (
        SELECT  MAX(history_id) AS mid
        FROM    history
        GROUP BY
                version_id
        ) q
JOIN    history h
ON      h.history_id = q.mid
```

Create a composite index on `(version_id, history_id)` for this to work fast.

Comment: Thanks for the response Quassnoi. Unfortunately, there is no performance improvement with the query you suggested.

Comment: @Sachin: what does this query return: `SELECT  COUNT(*), COUNT(DISTINCT version_id) FROM history`? Also, create a composite index as suggested in the post update.

Comment: Result of select query : +----------+------------------------------------+
| count(*) | count(DISTINCT CS_File_version_id) |
+----------+------------------------------------+
|   472468 |                              81941 |
+----------+------------------------------------+
I have also created the index.

Comment: @Sachin: please create the index and post the runtime and the plans for both queries (your original one an mine).

Comment: Thanks Quassnoi. After the creation of index, it seems to be running with velocity of light. Thanks.